# Sterilize Asp.Net Textbox Before Submitting to prevent SQL Injection

Tags: sql, asp.net, oracle, sql-injection

I have a task to prevent SQL Injection in an ASP.Net Web App. There is a comments textbox that the testers have flagged as possible location for SQL Injection. The Submit button event which inserts the text into the database already uses an Oracle parameterized SQLCommand. But when testing I was able to insert "select 'duff' from dual;" as a comment. So I'm curious as to how to prevent a sql injection when all I can find is people saying use parameters. All advise is appreciated. Thank you. Below are the lines that call the stored proc.

```
dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("ABC.Insert_My_Comment");
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "in_comments", DbType.String, obj.Comments);
db.ExecuteNonQuery(dbCommand);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Did the users tag this for a potential sql injection on the sole reasoning of it being a text box?

Comment: I'm guessing that's the reasoning behind this. But I'm somehow supposed to prevent any type of SQL from being inserted. I have thought about a regex validation, but do you know of any other methods? And thank you for the comments.

Comment: You are supposed to prevent the text of a sql query from being inserted into a comment field? That doesn't seem like a good use of your time to be honest. Are the comments run as queries against the database? That is not the same as preventing a SQL injection. Injection would be if someone put `'); DROP TABLE COMMENTS;` into the comment box and it actually dropped the table. Which it wont, since your code will just put that text into the comment field. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, perfectly makes since to me. But I'm thinking the testers aren't really coders and flagged it just because they are able to add a select statement as a comment, one that didn't return any results may I add. :)  But regardless, I either have to find a solution or documentation to prove of the impossibility of a successful injection attack. Ahh, good times.

Comment: Well the fact that the query got entered as a comment should be a good indicator that the query wasn't executed against the database... but this documentation should be sufficient https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx

Comment: I should qualify that statement with the assumption that the content of your sproc isn't something like "EXEC @in_comments" or something like that, to which a user could simply enter `DROP TABLE COMMENTS` to drop the table.

Comment: Yeah, it's safe to say it's not an exec statement. I'll look over the MSDN and see if I can send this back with our DBA's emails and see about getting this one pushed back. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Injection**

As long as you are using parameters and stored procedures, your system is reasonably protected from SQL injection.

If your penetration testers are still giving you a hard time about it, tell them you implemented a mitigation consistent with [OWASP guidance](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_2:_Stored_Procedures), specifically option 2.  If they keep giving you a hard time, ask them which specific [injection test](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005)#Example_1_.28classical_SQL_Injection.29:) failed, what is the specific [failure mode or criticality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Failure_mode,_effects,_and_criticality_analysis),
 and/or if they have been able to trigger any malicious or unwanted system behavior. If they cannot provide a specific case of expected behavior differing from actual behavior, it is not an actionable defect, and you should close it as [FAD](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Functions-As-Designed-(FAD).html).

**Other types of injection**

Just because you're safe from SQL injection doesn't mean you're not safe from all types of injection, e.g. someone could inject HTML into that field in possible support of a [reflected XSS attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Reflected_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-001)).  If there are any pages in your site that spit that comment field back out onto a page, make sure you are HTML-encoding the content properly and make sure nobody can coerce your site into rendering `Script` tags in the middle of your page.

Comment: That is an awesome answer. I didn't even think about the reflected XSS attack. I will make sure HTML-encoding is used. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're putting the comment in a parameter, it cant be used for injection.

The problem arises when you generate a dynamic query string like;
 `"INSERT INTO COMMENTS Comment = '" + userComment + "'"`